# Probability of Sum of 4 of 1st 10 Primes Being Odd

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

It seems to me that there is a mistake in the official solution to the following problem offered on Alcumus:

> Four prime numbers are randomly selected without replacement from the
>   first ten prime numbers. What is the probability that the sum of the
>   four selected numbers is odd? Express your answer as a common
>   fraction.

The official solution reads as follows:

> The first 10 prime numbers are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, and 29.
>   The sum of four of these numbers is only odd if 2, the only even
>   number on the list, is among them because the sum of four odd numbers
>   is even. Once 2 is picked, there are $\binom{9}{3}=\frac{9!}{3!6!}=84$
>   ways to pick three numbers from the remaining nine. The total number
>   of ways to select four prime numbers from the ten is
>   $\binom{10}{4}=\frac{10!}{4!6!}=210$. Therefore, the probability that
>   the sum of the four selected numbers is odd is
>   $\frac{84}{210}=\mathbf{\frac{2}{5}}$.

The way I see it, there are two ways to come up with an odd sum:
1. *by choosing three evens and one odd* 
2. *by choosing three odds and one even*

This would seem to imply that not all of the $\binom{9}{3}=\frac{9!}{3!6!}=84$ ways of choosing the remaining three numbers, once two has been chosen, are valid.  Some of these choices will leave one with two odds and two evens, which has an even sum.

When I computed the probability, I reasoned as follows

```
P(sum is odd) = P(three odds and 1 even) + P(three evens and one odd)
P(sum is odd) = (9/10 * 9/10 * 9/10 * 1/10) + (1/10 * 1/10 * 1/10 * 9/10)
p(sum is odd) = 738/1000
```

I've been wrong before about catching a mistake on Alcumus, so I think it's likely I could be wrong again.  Can anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: There is only one even prime.

Comment: I think the key words you may have overlooked is "selected without replacement"

Comment: Your computation is hard to follow.  You appear to be assuming replacement, though the problem is quite clear that there is no replacement.  Also you seem to be specifying the order in which the odd and even primes are chosen, counter to your intent.  Also your denominator is incorrect.

Comment: @lulu  I see the error that I made in assuming there was replacement.  But I don't think the order matters in my calculation, does it?  Multiplication is commutative, after all

Comment: Your formula, say $P(\text { three odd one even})=\frac 9{10}\times \frac 9{10}\times \frac 9{10}\times \frac 1{10}$ computes the probability that the first three are odd and the fourth is even (assuming replacement).  And, as I say, you get the denominator wrong.

Comment: @lulu  ...which would be the same probability as the first being even and the last three being odd, no?  So how is the order relevant?  I know the denominator is wrong; as I mentioned, I mistakenly assumed replacement.

Comment: Just think about it.  $OOOE, \,EOOO, OEOO, OOEO$ are four separate events.  True, they each have the same probability, but you have to consider all four of them!

Comment: @lulu  Ahh, that clears it up, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze  As I've already stated, I didn't realize that the items were to be drawn without replacement.  If they were replaced, 3 twos would be possible.

Comment: @ David J. You are right. I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that the “prime numbers are randomly selected **without replacement**” (emphasis mine) and therefore the prime number $2$ can be selected only once, at most. So, choosing three even primes and one odd one is not a possibility.

Comment: I still get caught on dumb mistakes like this semi-frequently.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DavidJ. So the courteous thing to do is to accept his answer!

Comment: @almagest  I was going to, it was too early to accept when I wrote my message.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of four odd numbers is always even. The sum of an even and an odd number is always odd. The sum of four prime numbers out of the first ten prime numbers can only be odd if it contains $2$ as one of the four prime numbers.

Comment: Sorry, that was an unhelpful comment.